# Compiler can't find ui_xyz.h file

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans

I've install Netbeans 7.2 and Qt 5 on Windows7. Everything compiles fine.

But recently when I create a Qt form and try to use it in this way:

- New Project > C/C++ Qt Application > Finish
- Right click on new Qt project > New > Qt Form > Finish
- After saving ui file in Designer

This error appears:

> newForm.h:11:24: fatal error: ui_newForm.h: No such file or directory

The content of main.cpp is :

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include "newForm.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // initialize resources, if needed
    // Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resfile);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    // create and show your widgets here

    return app.exec();
}
```

I tried to manually create ui_xwz.h file and add it to my project. But I want it work automatically as same as before. How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you checked whether newForm has added the macro Q_OBJECT ?

Comment: if you mean `newFile.h`, yes, it has `Q_OBJECT` right after class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a ridiculous solution, Maybe we should report it as a bug to Netbeans or Qt.

[image]

Go and active QtSVG and QtXml modules of your project and rebuild it. I tested this way and the problem vanished.